# Python. Can not open ZipFile

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of `*.tar.xz` archives. Each of them may contain APK or JAR files, that indeed are zip archives. I'm trying to search for some pattern inside content of that zip archives. I use next code to accomplish it:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import os
import glob
import tarfile
import shutil
import zipfile

def check(filename):
    if 'my_awesome_pattern' in open(file).read():
        print('matches')

def process_zip(f):
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r')     # <- here problem occurs
    z.extractall('tmp')
    z.close()  

def process_jar(file):
    print('JAR')
    process_zip(file)

def process_apk(file):
    print('APK')
    process_zip(file)

def process_xml(file):
    print('XML')
    check(file)

def process_tar(filename):
    print(filename)
    tar = tarfile.open(filename)
    for entry in tar.getnames():
        print(">>> " + entry)
        if entry.endswith('xml'):
            tar.extract(entry)
            process_xml(entry)
            os.remove(entry)
        elif entry.endswith('jar'):
            tar.extract(entry)
            process_jar(entry)
            os.remove(entry)
        elif entry.endswith('apk'):
            tar.extract(entry)
            process_apk(entry)
            os.remove(entry)

    tar.close()


for file in glob.glob("*.tar.xz"):
    process_tar(file)
```

But runtime stops with:

```
setupwizardtablet-all.tar.xz
>>> setupwizardtablet-all
>>> setupwizardtablet-all/nodpi
>>> setupwizardtablet-all/nodpi/priv-app
>>> setupwizardtablet-all/nodpi/priv-app/SetupWizard
>>> setupwizardtablet-all/nodpi/priv-app/SetupWizard/SetupWizard.apk
APK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./scan.py", line 56, in <module>
    process_tar(file)
  File "./scan.py", line 49, in process_tar
    process_apk(entry)
  File "./scan.py", line 27, in process_apk
    process_zip(file)
  File "./scan.py", line 16, in process_zip
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'r')     # <- here problem occurs
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 937, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 1034, in _RealGetContents
    x._decodeExtra()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/zipfile.py", line 415, in _decodeExtra
    tp, ln = unpack('<HH', extra[:4])
struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 4
```

And I've stuck with this error. Python is not my cup of tea, so I'm looking for help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Python is not my cup of tea, so I'm looking for help.* <= why do you use it, then? As for the question: Are you sure the apk is a proper .zip archive? Have you tested with external tools?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://bugs.python.org/issue14315) is related

Comment: @dhke Python is the most appropriate tool to automate my task. And APK seems to be OK. At least `unzip`  unpacks it without any warnings.

Comment: @MachineLearning Yes this is my case, I guess. Should not occur due I use Python 3.4.0. Thanks for link!

Comment: @Serhio So the solution is probably to upgrade to a newer Python version or manually pull in a local `zipfile` module. And bugger google to create standard-conforming zip-files ;-)

Comment: @Serhio You're welcome. I think it occurs in Python 3.4 and 3.5, so I assume it should be fixed in Python 3.6